# Spring WebSocket Client: Handshake failed due to unsupported WebSocket version: 8. Supported versions: [13]

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I built a very standard SpringBoot WebSockets project with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig : AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer() {

    override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
    }

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/offer")
    }

}
```

When I try to connect to my WebSocket with Java Stomp Client I get this on console:

```
Handshake failed due to unsupported WebSocket version: 8. Supported versions: [13]
```

And therefore I am not being able to connect or do anything...

Can anyone help me on this? Its been 1 week since I started struggling around this error.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Due to time constraints I ended up not using STOMP as the sub protocol and went for WebSocket only. Still using Spring though.